# How to handle Route Guard & Async ionic.storage in Ionic 4?

Tags: asynchronous, routes, jwt, ionic4, guard

I would like to use Guard with Async getting of user token stored in the async local storage. I tried following:

```
canActivate(): boolean {

    return this.lsProvider
        .getValue(Constants.KEY_USER_TOKEN)
        .map(value => value != null)
        .first();
```

I tried the approach using subscribe too but without luck:

```
this.lsProvider
        .getValue(Constants.KEY_USER_TOKEN).subscribe(isSuccess => {
      if (isSuccess) {
        return true;
      }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    }
```

The helper method is following and is returning Promise

```
getValue(key: string) {
    console.log("getValue " + key);
    return this.storage.get(key);
  }
```

I would like to avoid using Event broadcasting in this case. Should I use async/await or something different? Any example appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From **[Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)** the interface of `canActivate` tells that the return type can be an observable, a promise or just a boolean (among others):

```
interface CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree
}
```

So if `getValue()` returns a promise, you could use `canActivate` like this:

```
public canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
  return this.lsProvider
        .getValue(Constants.KEY_USER_TOKEN)
        .then(value => value != null)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the example is not working. I am redirected to root URL (localhost:8100). If I tried to force return false from canActivate I am successfully redirected to login.

Comment: @redrom what do you mean by redirected to root url? A guard only decides if the page where it is assigned to can be loaded or not. Where are you trying to redirect the user?